# Is there a less clunky way to interact with an AWS worker tier?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application which is running a web server environment and a worker tier environment.  My goal is to pass some parameters to an endpoint in the web server which submits a request to the worker which will then go off and do a long computation and write the results to an S3 bucket.  For now I'm ignoring the "long computation" part and just writing a little hello world application which simulates the workflow.  Here's my Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import boto3
import json

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/web")
def test():
    data = json.dumps({"file": request.args["file"], "message": request.args["message"]})
    boto3.client("sqs").send_message(
        QueueUrl = "really_really_long_url_for_the_workers_sqs_queue",
        MessageBody = data)
    return data

@application.route("/worker", methods = ["POST"])
def worker():
    data = request.get_json()
    boto3.resource("s3").Bucket("myBucket").put_object(Key = data["file"], Body = data["message"])
    return data["message"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug = True)
```

(Note that I changed the worker's HTTP Path from the default `/` to `/worker`.)  I deployed this application to both the web server and to the worker, and it does exactly what I expected.  Of course, I had to do the usual IAMS configuration.

What I don't like about this is the fact that I have to hard code my worker's SQS URL into my web server code.  This makes it more complicated to change which queue the worker polls, and more complicated to add additional workers, both of which will be convenient in production.  I would like some code which says "send this message to whatever queue worker X is currently polling".  It's obviously not a huge deal, but I thought I would see if anyone knows a way to do this.

Comment: Can you build up the URL dynamically, following some protocol? Or are you given a unique URL that you have to use and there's no pattern to it?

Comment: @JAB By default Amazon assigns a URL to the worker, and the URL is a disaster (probably randomly generated); I speculate that they have to be globally unique.  It might be possible to create queues manually with more predictable URLs, but this leads to other problems - for instance, modifying the worker's settings would no longer automatically modify the corresponding settings for its queue.

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of the queue URLs, you may want to try keeping them in some external storage (an in-memory database or key-value store, perhaps) that associates the URLs with the IDs of the workers currently using them. That way you can update them as need be without having to modify your application. (The downside would be that you then have [an] additional source[s] of data to maintain and you'd need to write the interfacing code for both the server and workers.)